# Library that handles displaying/scrolling/zooming of maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, geolocation

To avoid to re-invent the wheel again and again: a very common task for Android apps is displaying of maps (optionally using data from Google, Google Satellite, OSM), scrolling these maps, zooming in and out and drawing some own, additional data into them.

I want to avoid to implement something that already exists in a mature state, so my question: is there a free library available that performs these tasks and that could be used in own Apps too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this ?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: No support for OSM (as far as I know). I'd prefer to offer both to my users, OSM and Google. And I personally prefer OSM since Googles map data don't contain as much information as OSM and are more ugly...IMHO.